# BIRT Incosistent rendering

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

I'm having a very odd behavior rendering PDFs between BIRT Designer and Runtime. (Image attached)

The left image was generated by the BIRT designer and the right by BIRT runtime. I want to generate the left image using the runtime.

I'm using BIRT 3.7.2 for the runtime and designer

Are there any properties that I have to set somewhere?

Thanks!

[image: inconsistencies]

Comment: Did you set this manualy? Or left for auto (this might be the cause). Thry to set both horisontal and vertical alignment manually.
On totally unrelated matter, why are you using the ancient BIRT version?

Comment: Hi @szefuf thanks for the answer. Nope I haven't set this manually. its style dictates that is has no padding, margins or alignments set. The weird thing is the same report template is generated correctly with the designer than generating it using the runtime. We have some visual changes on the designer that's why we have stuck with this particular version. by the way, I have tried using runtime version 4.0.4 but the issue still persists.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is top padding. This could also be an issue of the rendering engine, not of the PDF. Try to save both outputs to the file system and view them with the same PDF rendering application (typically, that's Adobe Reader). Modern browsers include their own PDF rendering engines which might behave a little different.

Comment: hi @hvb, the template has zero padding on all sides. Ideally, it should be centered (as the image on the left). Unfortunately, this is not the case. I used exactly the same templates but they render differently. I'm leaning more of this becoming a rendering engine problem but I cannot see any significant code difference on invocation of the BIRT engine between the designer and the BIRT Runtime...